# Display cell below previous cell

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I have a structure per the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>z</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And, using CSS, I want to see this following result (without visible borders):

```
+---+---+
| a | b |
|   | c |
+---+---+
| x | y |
|   | z |
+---+---+
```

To elaborate on my motivation: The table is an overview of job history, and the columns are period, position, and employer. I want to put the employer below the position for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on kapa's answer, I arrived at the following working solution:

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
td.above, td.above + td {
    display: block;
}
```

For HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td class="above">b</td>
    <td>c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td class="above">y</td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
```

See [jsfiddle.net/pjhmU/9](http://jsfiddle.net/pjhmU/9).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with CSS using the normal table layout. Table elements have special `display` properties (`table`, `table-row`, etc), but you can reset them to `block` to make them act like normal boxes (like a `div`, you know):

```
table, tbody, tr, td { 
    display: block; 
}
```

and then build your own structure, an example with floats:

```
tr { 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

td {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

td:first-child {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjhmU/)

This way you can preserve your semantic information, but style it according to your special needs.

Comment: Super..way to do it exactly

Comment: @krainert Browser support might not be the happiest one. Chrome and Firefox behaves as they should, but IE9 (and of course all the older ones) insists on the table layout. Could not test yet with IE10 or 11.

Comment: After toying around with kapa's solution, I arrived at this: http://jsfiddle.net/pjhmU/9/ Since this approach seem a little more accurate and minimal, should I post it as an answer instead of accepting kapa's answer?

Comment: @krainert Feel free to post it and accept your own answer. Happy I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way to do that.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, I'd like to preserve semantic sensibility, and your example (also my own first thought) would fail to capture the table as a list of `(a, b, c)` tuples.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit css voodoo but it actually works for most browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/FyLJh/

Generally keep table styles and only change the one you want to realign:

```
th { vertical-align: top; }
td { display: block; }
```

I used th + td here but you could of course also just do this with a class.

Answer (score 1):

Though i agree with Kappa solution, but considering you don't wanna change the default `table` layout to `block`, here is another [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pjhmU/2/) which is a cross **browser with IE support**!!

```
td {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
td:first-child {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    content:" ";
    float:right;
    width:60%;
    margin-top:-20px;
    text-align:center;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    content:" ";
    float:right;
    width:60%;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**NOTE** : The :nth-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.So in case if you want the support for old ones too.... [**here is the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pjhmU/3/)

The trick is to replace all the `childs` with a `class`

Comment: +1 Nice one, even though floating still changes the table layout, but at least IE understands. I only changed everything to `block` to make it more consistent and safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">z</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using colspan in html email

Comment: why not? it's very widely supported. Can you name a client that doesn't support `colspan`?

Comment: @OneEightLeft..email?? any where mentioned in the question??

Comment: @Avinash I mistook the html-table tag for html-email... But why else would you be writing in tables?

Comment: @OneEightLeft because you have tabular data maybe? ;)

Comment: Thank you for the point, OneEightLeft, but as Avinash suggests, I don't need it for emails in this case. And yes, tabular data indeed!

Comment: @OneEightLeft "Don't use tables for layout" != "Don't use tables at all"

Comment: @michalrybak they are supported, but are very buggy and outlook isn't the nicest with them. Best practice is to use nested tables. But thats completely off topic now.

Comment: `align` is a deprecated attribute, only valid in HTML4.

Answer (score 0):

please use this structure

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td style="width:50px"><span>b</span><span>c</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td style="width:50px"><span>e</span><span>f</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd like to preserve the `(a, b, c)` tuples for semantic clarity. (Also, I need the cell width to fit the contents.)

Comment: You can set relative width for your table and your cell,also you can set float:right;clear:both to all span in css,It's works correctly